# Set permissions so that Apache and I will be able to edit files

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, file-permissions

I'm on a Mac, but I guess it applies to Linux too, since I'm using a command line.
When I write web applications, the apache user (which is _www on a Mac) has to be able to edit files as well as me.

Also, I don't want to set this for every single file or folder, I would like to set up the root folder and then I and _www will have access to every file inside this root directory.

As it stands now, I have to use chown or edit with sudo to accomplish things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add yourself to the group `_www` and add write permission to the group.

```
 usermod -a -G _www your_username 
 chgrp _www filename
 chmod 775 filename
```

Comment: Great, thanks! This got me to an answer, so I'm set you answer to accepted.

Just two things I had to do also / differently:
`useradd` is not a command on a Mac, so I had to use this command:
`sudo dscl . append /groups/_www GroupMembership my_username`.

Also I had to do `sudo chmod -R g+w root_folder` so that the _www group (which I am a part of now) can write to files.